# Force encoding on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an `iframe` with a `src` attribute. The document that the iframe is loading does not have proper charset information (neither as part of the response headers nor does it have a meta charset tag). What's the best way (i.e. if possible) to force a particular charset on the iframe?

My constraints:

- Don't have access to the server serving the document or the sub-document.
- Can modify html as well as inject some JS into the main document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. At least, not in any generally applicable way.

The encoding of an HTML document is determined by the browser based on the HTTP headers in the response, `<meta>` tags in the HTML document, and, in some cases, the user's browser preferences. This process cannot generally be influenced by Javascript at all, and certainly not on a cross-origin basis. (In particular, adding `<meta>` tags after the fact doesn't work; the character set is determined at the time of document loading, and can't be changed later on.)

If the document you're loading has incorrect character set headers, you're pretty much out of luck. You'll need to get the server administrator to start sending the correct charset in `Content-Type` headers, get a meta tag added to force the correct charset, or get all your users to force the appropriate encoding for this site in their browser settings.

Comment: Yep, was just hoping that there'd be some hack that I could use. :(
Will accept if no good hacks in a little while.